# VS code Debugger cant the Program C# on Ubuntu OS

Tags: debugging, c#, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Visual Studio Code, i installed it on my Ubuntu Machine and installed the debugger. 
i can run my program normally by using the "donnet run" command.
i configured the the debugger by adding  the:`"csharp.fallbackDebuggerLinuxRuntimeId": "ubuntu.16.10-x64"
to the settings.json file, and chenged the launch.json  to point to my dll like this

```
{
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/Code.dll>",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "console": "internalConsole"
    }
```

**and now on i get this on my screen** [image]

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 0):

I Found The problem and fixed it it was a syntax issue

```
{
    "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
    "type": "coreclr",
    "request": "launch",
    "preLaunchTask": "build",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/Code.dll>",
    "args": [],
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "console": "internalConsole"
}
```

THe **">"** at the end of this line is the problem' its a leftover from the original code